# Regex to filter int from url

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to filter out a value of a url.

The url looks like the following:

> http://userimages-akm.imvu.com/catalog/includes/modules/phpbb2/images/avatars/**145870556**_47076915459092eafd7b69.jpg

Now i'm trying to only receive the following part from the url: **145870556**

I thought about using a regex. But i won't get a working regex beside this one:

```
^((http[s]?|ftp):\/)?\/?([^:\/\s]+)((\/\w+)*\/)([\w\-\.]+[^#?\s]+)(.*)?(#[\w\-]+)?$
```

Is there a better regex to use?

Comment: `(?<=\/)\d+` ?.

Comment: Or without regex: [`explode("_", end(explode("/", $url)))[0];`](https://eval.in/789001)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the image filename always follows the same format `<timestamp>_<hex-value>.<extension>`, then you don't need to match the entire URL.

```
$url = 'http://userimages-akm.imvu.com/catalog/includes/modules/phpbb2/images/avatars/145870556_47076915459092eafd7b69.jpg';
preg_match_all('~\/(\d+)_.*$~', $url, $matches);

// $matches[1] = '145870556';
```

https://regex101.com/r/vsDnoj/2

Comment: `.*$` is redundant there.

Comment: For this example, perhaps. But I prefer to keep the regex as tight as possible to prevent possible mis-matches. Each to their own.

Comment: `.*$` does not make it any tight though. Just bloated (and slower) :-)